# How i can add comment with custom name author (admin panel)

Tags: wordpress

How can I add a comment with an arbitrary author name while logged into the admin panel as an administrator

Comment: Can you explain clearly?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not insert the comment through opening the page as any other user would do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really. But you can open the same page in a second window in "private mode" in your browser, in there you will not be logged in at all and therefore can use any name you want. Or open that page in another browser and use that to comment.